# Line graph with markers plotting a zero starting value rather than actual value

Tags: excel, vba, linegraph

I am doing a line graph with markers of four columns and the date on the x axis.

Column C is the values I want to plot.
The other columns (E to G) are constant lines to indicate the lower and upper limits (Quality control).

My first value in column C is 16.72 but the graph starts at 0.

Why is there a 0 value included and how can I remove it?

```vb
Dim RegChart As ChartObject

Set RegChart = Sheets("Regen Quality").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=800, Top:=7, Height:=300)
RegChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("RegenQuality").Range("A3:A80,C3:C80,E3:G80")
RegChart.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
RegChart.Chart.HasTitle = True
RegChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "%Regen"
'X axis name
RegChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
RegChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Sample dates"
'y-axis name
RegChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
RegChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had experiences doing this. You can edit the axis options so it won't start with 0, for example below:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 16.72
```

You may actually edit the axis options manually in the chart and record the macro to see the output that you prefer and its corresponding code. Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help!